# Setting up group disk quotas

Tags: filesystem, quota

I am hoping to get some advice in setting up disk quotas.  So, I know about:

- Adding usrquota and grpquota on to `/etc/fstab` for the file systems that need to be managed.
- Using edquota to assign disk quotas to users.

However, I need to do the last step for multiple users and edquota seems to be a bit troublesome.

One solution that I have found is that I can do:  `sudo edquota -u foo -p bar`.  This will copy the disk quota of bar to user foo.  I was wondering if this is the best solution?

I tried setting up group disk quotas but they don't seem to be working.  Are group quotas meant to help in the assignment of the same quota to multiple users?  Or are they suppose to give a total limit to a set of users?  For example, if users A, B, C are in group X then assigning a quota of 20 GB gives each user 20 GB or does it give 20 GB to the entire group X to divide up?  I'm interested in doing the former, but not the latter.

Right now, I've assigned group disk quotas and they aren't working.  So, I guess it is due to my misunderstanding of group disk quotas...

My problem is I want to easily give the same quota to multiple users; any suggestions on the best way to do this out of what I've tried above or anything else I may not have thought of?

Thank you!

Comment: You may want to take a look at this [User / Group Disk Quotas A three Step Guide](http://abhishek.nagar.me/blogs/user-group-disk-quotas-three-step-guide)

Comment: Thanks!  Hmmm, that doesn't seem to say anything new.  But it ends with **edquota -u foo -p bar** as the way to copy quota from one person to another.  So, this is the way and not through groups?