# How to set limits on how much stuff each account can store?

Tags: 13.10

I want to set a limit on how much each account can store, on Ubuntu 13.10. Is there a way to do this?

For example, I want to make it so each person can only store 40 GBs on their account

Answer (score 1):

Disk quotas must be established, and [this YoLinux page](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialQuotas.html) illustrates the procedure, and [this AskUbuntu page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/177295/setting-up-group-disk-quotas) will also illustrate the concept.

A brief overview follows:

00) Decide if you want to assign storage limits individually or set by group.
0) If by group, create the group and assign users to it.
1) Edit file ***/etc/fstab***  to add qualifier "usrquota" or "grpquota" to the partition
2) Set the name for the quota, with

> touch /partition/aquota.user

where the partition might be ***/home*** or some partition defined in ***/etc/fstab*** , then do (root should be the owner of the quota file) `chmod 600 /partition/aquota.user`

3) Re-mount the file partition with quotas, or reboot.

4) `quotacheck -vgum /partition`  to scan a file system for disk usages, and update the quota record file "quota.user/aquota.user" to the most recent status. It's good to make sure this runs every reboot as well as weekly-to-quarterly with ***cron***.

5) `quotaon -av` (and I'd watch for the result at reboot time)

6) 'edquota -u user_id' - and if you get zeros, something's broken (use 'edquota -g group_name' for groups, instead)

7) `quota -u user_id` will list the quota for that user, `quota -q` shows users over the quota limit and you can get a quota summary report with  `repquota -a`

Comment: Is there a simplier way to do it? Just wondering. And thank you for helping, btw

Comment: The "Ask Ubuntu" way of thanking a fellow user is by up-voting and/or accepting their answer :-)